# RSA encryption in iPhone using .NET generated public key?

Tags: c#, iphone, .net, ios4, cryptography

How can i encrypt data using RSA encryption in iOS?. I want to encrypt using public key that is send from .NET. is it possible?. How can i send public key from .NET webservice?.

Thanks in Advance,
Sanal

Comment: What you want to do is use SSL. It sends a public key from the server and uses RSA (typically), but does so using a very mature well studied and designed security protocol. You write code to well-designed high-level APIs to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can i encrypt data using RSA encryption in iOS?

Several choice. If you use C or ObjectiveC then the easiest way is to use [CommonCrypto](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/Security_Overview/Architecture/Architecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000976-CH202-TPXREF101).

You can also use C# and the .NET framework on your iOS devices with [MonoTouch](http://ios.xamarin.com/) (disclaimer, I work for Xamarin) and share code between your web service and device.

> I want to encrypt using public key that is send from .NET. is it possible?

Yes. You generally encrypt the (potentially large) using a symmetric key (e.g. AES) then encrypt the symmetric (secret) key using the public key. See my old blog entry for [more details](http://pages.infinit.net/ctech/20031101-0151.html).

> How can i send public key from .NET webservice?

You can send it as XML, call **rsa.ToXmlString ()** to get the public key in the xmldsig-defined format.

Note that it's unclear, from your previous answer, if the web services encrypts (and the iOS client decrypts) or the other way around (could be both too). You'll want to take care where the private key is generated and how the keys are transfered between the service and device (e.g. using https).

Comment: I have both way data transfer. So where can i store Private key?.

Comment: Ideally each side has it's own private key, each protected by their operating system. That way it's never transfered over any network.

Comment: is there any sample code available, for .NET - iPhone RSA encryption.